# Installing ubuntu on a mac mini using blutooth mouse/keyboard

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, mac-mini

I tried to install ubuntu on my mac mini. the first step is textual (we can choose to check hard drive, try ubuntu, install ubuntu, oem install) and my keyboard apple blutooth work just well but  at the moment im enter in the graphical installation my keyboard and my mouse dont work HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I did not get that to work either, i found it easyer to just plug in a usb mouse/kb afterwards once its installed bluetooth kb worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This does not actually answer the question.